# Does anyone else know about Al's lower half?

Tags: son-of-zorn

At the end of S1E1, we see that

> Alangulon's body from the waist down is animated.

I would suspect Zorn and Edie *MUST* know since he is their biological son. However, there are enough common interactions with other people (thinking gym class here) that it could be common knowledge.

Is there proof anyone else knows about this, or was the scene just a reveal to us as the audience?

Comment: The bully didn't know about it until he saw it. Alangulon had been hiding it from gym class. So it can't be *that* common knowledge.